# Project won't import after clicking finish button in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to import existing project in to my workspace. I import the project from files -> open project from file system. After showing the exact path and click finish. But the project is not showing in file explorer. Are there any reason for this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the project is not showing in file explorer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me once when I had the same project already opened in the workspace.
If you're unsure about Eclipse's workspaces, check this page: [What is a Workspace](https://dvteclipse.com/documentation/pss/What_is_a_Workspace.html).

Could you check if the same project or a project with same name is already there?